# What is the maximal path of a tree?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

Could anyone explain obviously what the maximal path is ? Is it necessary for a tree that has two maximal paths that share no common vertex ?

Comment: This question is rather unclear. A single vertex is a tree, Or two vertices with one edge joining them. Or a star - a single vertex joined by an edge to as many vertices as you like, and no other edges exist. And a graph with more than one component can have maximal paths in each component. Please clarify the question.

Comment: @MarkBennet I meant a connected graph that graph has two maximal paths that share no common vertex ? And, I had two questions, first whatis the maximal path of a tree, second, is it possible for a graph that has two maximal paths that share no common vertex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you mean by *maximal*. Usually maximal is different from maximum in the following sense: a *maximal path* can mean a path that cannot be made any longer; in other words, at each end there is a vertex all of whose neighbours are already on the path.

Note that under this definition, a maximal path is not necessarily a path of maximum length. Here is one such example ($A-B-C$):

```
  A
  |
o—B—o—o—o—o—o
  |
  C
```

Comment: Oh wow, I was way off. This is usually what is meant by maximal path.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I think your answer is helpful too, though, because it's not entirely clear what the OP is asking ...

Comment: @Théophile thanks for answering. I meant a conncected graph, and your explanation is so clear.

Comment: @Rinzler Okay, I'm glad the explanation helped. In that case, you can see that two maximal paths won't necessarily intersect.

Answer (score 7):

I will assume that you meant a *connected* tree. Also, I am using *maximal* to mean "of maximal length," which may not be what you meant.

A *path* in a tree is a sequence of vertices, with no repeats, where successive vertices in the sequence are adjacent. If a path $P$ is at least as long as any other path, then that path is *maximal*. It is possible for there to be more than one maximal path. For example, in this tree,

```
     C
    /
A--B
    \
     D
```

both of the paths $A,B,C$ and $A,B,D$ are maximal, since they are of length $3$, and there are no paths of length $4$ or greater.

Note that these two paths share a common vertex. This is always true: any two maximal paths will share a common vertex.

Why? Suppose you had two disjoint paths, $P_1=v_1,v_2\dots,v_n$ and $P_2=w_1,w_2\dots, w_n$. Consider the pair $v_i,w_j$ for which the distance between $v_i$ and $w_j$ is minimal (here, distance means the length of the shortest path connecting them). Then there is a path $v_i,p_1,p_2,\dots,p_k,w_j$ which connects $v_i$ and $w_j$. None of the intermediate vertices $p_1,\dots,p_k$ can be in $P_1$ or the $P_2$, because of the minimality when we chose $v_i$ and $w_j$. This implies that $P_1$ and $P_2$ weren't maximal, since at least one of the following paths are longer:
$$
v_1,\dots,v_i,p_1,\dots,p_kw_j,\dots,w_n
$$
$$
w_1,\dots,w_j,p_k,\dots,p_1,v_i,\dots,v_n
$$
We have shown that disjoint paths are not maximal, which means that any two maximal paths intersect.

Comment: From your answer, I concluded that any two maximal paths have to share a  common vertex.

Comment: @Rinzler That is correct, as long as "maximal" means what I think it means. There are two definitions of maximal, one given in my answer, one given in Theophile's. By my definition, what you said is correct, by his definition, what you said is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible for that a tree that has two maximal paths that share no common vertex .

```
      o
      |
      o
      |
o     o         o
 \    |        /
  o - o - o - o
 /        |    \
o         o     o
          |
          o
          |
          o
```

As shown above, the graph of a tree has two maximal paths that share no common vertex. The length of the maximal paths is 5.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by *maximal path*.  There is a path of length $7$ (the two vertical lines and their connection).  On the other hand the are several paths which cannot be extended and do not share a vertex, such as the two of length $2$ which have sloping edges.

Answer (score -1):

**Maximal path** in a graph **G** is a path **P** in **G** that is not contained in a longer path.

When a graph is finite, no path can extend forever, so maximal(non-extendible) paths exist.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your answer adds nothing new to the already existing answers.